# File Upload in Flask - 400 Bad Request

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to do a file upload to my Flask backend via AJAX in JQuery.

My Python side looks like this:

```
@app.route('/upload/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('uploadfile.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        file_val = request.files['file']
        return 'it worked!'
```

Note that it works when I do a normal submit of the form.

My HTML and AJAX looks like this:

```
<form id="upload-file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
    <label for="file">Select a file</label>
    <input name="file" type="file">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <button id="upload-file-btn" type="button">Upload</button>
</fieldset>
```

```
$(document).on("click", "#upload-file-btn", function() {
    var form_data = new FormData($('#input-file')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/upload/',
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("UREKA!!!");
        },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

However, I'm getting a 400 response when the AJAX request is performed. I'm thinking this is something to do with the contentType, but would really appreciate any guidance :)

Comment: Does Flask itself say anything? (Is debugging on?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any element with this id `$('#input-file')`, my guess either you want to have form's id or just `input[type="file"]`'s id.

You might try with this:

```
var form_data = new FormData($('input[type="file"]')[0]);
```